# Не получается использовать функции из своих пакетов на golang

Tags: golang, package

Имеется такая архитектура

```
/src
  /sample
    sample.go
    /util
       calc.go
```

**calc.go**

```
package util
func sum(a,b int) int {
  return a+b
}
```

**sample.go**

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
"./util"
)
func main(){
  l:=util.sum(10,20)
  fmt.Println(l)
}
```

Выполняю `go run sample.go`

Получаю:

```
./sample.go:10: cannot refer to unexported name util.sum
./sample.go:9: undefined: util.sum
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Экспортируемые (публичные) имена должны начинаться с большой буквы.

Переименуйте `sum` в `Sum`.

Comment: Спасибо.Теперь все работает!